# webserver replies to ?q="/path/to/file" with a "path bar" png

Tags: cocoa, macos, scripting

I want to write a CGI script that accepts a posix path as a string, and returns a png representing it. Eg:

---

If the script is sent the string
 **/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app**,

it will return the following png file:  [image: /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app]

---

An example based in any scripting platform that comes bundled with the Mac is fine by me (Python, Perl, AppleScript, BASH). I might not know it, but I can muddle through to get an idea of what I need to do.

I think what I'm looking for is a way to generate an NSPathCell-style widget, and dump its contents into an image file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get image data from a path like this:

1) Create an '**[NSPathControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSPathControl_class/Reference/Reference.html)**'

2) Use the control's '**setPathCtrl:toURLStr:**' to have it display the URL of your choice.

3) Call the control's '**getPngDataFromNSView:**' and it will give you your desired image data.

4) Now you can save the data to a file using '**writePngData:**'

If Obj-C isn't an option, you can use PyObjC bridging from Python.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on the context, it might be reasonable to use `-dataWithPDFInsideRect:` instead of generating a PNG.

Of course, if you’re getting an image (especially a pixmap image) of a UI element like this for web use, there’s a 95 % chance that you deserve a punch in the face from the Accessibility Gorilla.

Comment: heh heh. and that's just if the Accessibility Gorilla remembered to eat breakfast

Answer (score 4):

That's an `NSPathControl`.  To take an `NSString` and split it up into the path components, you can invoke the `-[NSString pathComponents]` method.  If you want that *actual png*, you'd have to either do the rendering yourself or take an `NSPathControl`, force it to draw into a context that you control, and then turn that context into an image yourself.

Bigger question: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: this is webapp to run on my intranet. i sometimes put together documentation (how-to articles, etc) and i'm sick of doing a screen grab every time i want to add the path to a file. calling a cgi that returns png files would make this easier. i could just write the html and link to http://1.2.3.4/cgi?-/System/Library/foo-.png whenever i need a png to illustrate a path

Answer (score 2):

In response to the comment you posted on May 17: since this is a webapp, I would like to suggest writing a script that turns your file path into a styled HTML block that very closely resembles the single image result you originally asked for. You would use static icons for hard disk, folder, file, and the little gray arrow.

This way you could say:

```
<?php echo prettyPathHTML('/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app'); ?>
```

Comment: problem is... that's a lot of icons to figure out (like... thousands). not to mention, i will have to recreate the heuristic the OS uses to determine which icon to show for files that do not contain an icns (ie: most files) based on with which app they are associated. not fun. oh yeah, and when the OS is upgraded - i have to do all the work again. no thanks

Comment: Generic icons unacceptable, then? You're not making this easy for yourself :)

Comment: I know :( I want to be able to refer a novice to a "how-to" webpage. The greater the chance that the icons they see match the icons on the "how-to" webpage, the less chance they will be confused.